# Java Eclipse Egit - classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, egit

I have a problem because my Eclipse after installing egit plugin has gone mad.
First after installation it couldn't find swt library. Google told me the solution was bad linkage. Solved this by:

`ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/`

But now I have a trouble because it doesn't recognize path for standard library. Compilation works good but almost each word is underlined red. It is extremely annoying while working. 
Why oh why eclipse is so annoying.

Comment: That happened after installing EGit? Seems odd. Can you try with a fresh Eclipse Luna (was released a short while ago)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by invoking "Project Structure" window (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S) and changing SDK path to Java 1.8 installed on my system.

Installation of Egit probably reseted this path because nothing was selected.